# log4net fails to log

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

So for some reason our logger has stopped logging and I am at a complete loss as to why.
What I'm using in my project is the following:

The log4net configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="UdpAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" />
  </root>

  <appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <remoteAddress value="127.0.0.1" />
    <remotePort value="8180" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
      <locationInfo value="true" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/DA.RA.log"/>
    <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="10"/>
    <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
    <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
    <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%-5level %date %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

In my web.config I have the following line:

```xml
<section name="log4net" 
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3d255455d3dcb36" 
         requirePermission="false"/>
```

In my global.asax I have the following line in the application_start method:

```
string filename = Server.MapPath( @"~\XML\log4net.xml" );
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch( new System.IO.FileInfo( filename ) );
```

and when I call the logger in any of my pages I use:

```
private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ReportParameters));
```

I have tried many different things I found online. These include:

adding the following line to the assembly in my project

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch=true)]
```

I tried:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

I've upgraded the version of my log4net.dll from 1.2.10.0 to 1.2.11.0.

I tried adding the log4net appenders to the web.config file instead of in it's own file, and I still get nothing out of the logging.

Comment: Possibly a permissions issue on the folder where the log is being written?  That is a very common problem with log4net, especially if you're hosting within IIS.  I didn't 100% review your config, but from the sounds of it, this was working at some point and just stopped, right?  First thing of course is to find out what has changed!  If your config didn't change, then maybe folder permissions were changed?

Comment: Try this: <appender name="rollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">

Comment: Maybe something is failing and isn't loading log4net configurations at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try opening internal debugging of log4net and check or share the result:

Note: I made a sample app and used your same log4net.xml file and ConfigureAndWatch statement and it worked without a problem. I think you are having a filename path resolution problem or permission to write problem. Create log folder If you didn't.

You need to add to web.config

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true" />
 </appSettings>

 <system.diagnostics>
  <trace autoflush="true">
   <listeners>
    <add
     name="textWriterTraceListener"
     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
     initializeData="c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\log4net.txt" />
   </listeners>
  </trace>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Comment: I've tried this, but i'm not seeing the text file that would display the log in that location

Comment: I am pretty sure you are having a permission problem if you are doing exactly these. Both log4net internal debugging file and your log file creates on my computer.  try to create a folder like d:\temp and give everyone full access permission and test.  And also creating a new simple test application might help to debug or share with us.

Comment: It seems to be creating the log folder, but not the log file whenever i do something in the app that i know has logs used

Comment: That did the trick, it was a permission problem so now it's an adminstration problem and not a code issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Other than a possible file permission issue, I have found that when using

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator()]
```

in ASP.NET projects, that it would never actually do anything (I was using the debug string appender).

The solution for me was to start up log4net within the `Application_Start` even in global.asax.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}
```

Comment: Right, and that is what i have in the global.asax application_start method

Comment: @James213 whoops, glossed over that part, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```xml
<section name="log4net" 
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net, Version=1.2.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a3d255455d3dcb36" 
         requirePermission="false"/>
```

For this:

```xml
<section name="log4net" 
         type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net" 
         requirePermission="false"/>
```

And instead of

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch()
```

Call

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

Let me know if it works that way

Comment: I create a web site and add your configs and only worked after that changes that i mentioned. Remark that when i had reference to the log4net dll the xml goes with it. Also I put the configs in webConfig. Sorry it didn't help